# Resizing Images with Automator into multiple sizes

Tags: automator, graphics, display

I followed this simple guide to resize images in a batch with Automator:
copy

1. copy file to resized folder on Desktop
2. add suffix _S (for small)
3. resize it to 25% of its original size

[image: First Workflow]

Though I want to resize into multiple sizes:

1. copy file to resized folder on Desktop
2. add suffix _S (for small)
3. resize it to 25% of its original size
4. copy file
5. add suffix _M (for medium)
6. resize it to 50% of its original size

[image: Second Workflow]

Unfortunately this results in the second resize being applied to the already resized image.

So, is there a way to reset the chain back to the original file and not the resized file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to re-order your workflow a bit.

Instead of making the small size first, then the medium size, make the medium size first, then create the small size from the medium.

So your workflow would look like this:

1. **Copy Finder Items** to the folder you want
2. **Add Text** to append the `_M`
3. **Scale Images** to 50% (if that's the medium size you want)
4. **Copy Finder Items** to make the small file
5. Change the **Add Text** action to **Replace Text**, replace `_M` with `_S`
6. **Scale Images** to 50% (50% of the already scaled image will be 25% of the original)

This is what it should look like:
[image: workflow]

## General Method Using Variables

The above method works well for your particular situation, given the sizes you wanted. But if you need oddball sizes, or are doing some other action where feeding the output of the first task into the second won't work, Automator's variables can be used.

You can use the **Set Value of Variable** action to store the original input in a variable, then recall it for later use with the **Get Value of Variable** action.

With this method, your workflow would be:

1. **Set Value of Variable** and specify a variable name
2. **Copy Finder Items** to the folder you want for the small images
3. **Add Text** to append the `_S`
4. **Scale Images** to 25%
5. **Get Value of Variable** with *Ignore this action's input* checked (click the *Options* button on the action if you don't see this)

   - Make sure the variable selected is the one set in step 1
6. **Copy Finder Items** to the folder for medium images
7. **Add Text** to append `_M`
8. **Scale Images** to 50%

Comment: Very thorough answer, thanks a lot for that. I went the variable route and it worked like a charm. What should be added though is that "Ignore this action's input" must be checked on the "Get Value of Variable" action to ignore the initial input and take the variable contents instead. unfortunately I can't vote up with my low rep =(

Comment: Good catch on the ignore input setting. I checked that in my test workflow, but forgot to add it to the answer. I'll update it.