# Automator crop image is doubling the inputted dimensions

Tags: macos, photos, automator, services

I'm using the recommendation from this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70496) to create an Automator service that crops all photos I send to it. It works perfectly except that the crop automatically doubles the dimensions.

I've tried:

- deleting every step except for the crop and it still doubled the dimensions
- simply halving the entered dimensions but I need several crops to have an odd number for its size.

I need to crop photos to specific sizes for use on my company's website and can't just crop by percentage.

**How can I modify this service to achieve this?**

I'm doing this on a late 2013 MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra.

EDIT!!!

Here's the workflow: [image: Screenshot of workflow]

EDIT!!! I'm bad at this - adding more screenshots

Here are better screenshots
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have a Late 2013 MacBook Pro running High Sierra. I'm not cropping by percentage. I need to crop to specific sizes for uses on my company's website.

Comment: Is the difference about 2.5? If so, is it set to inches not cm?

Comment: The linked question isn't handling crop at all, so could you edit & add to your post exactly what your workflow is.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post to show the workflow. It's identical to the linked answer but the scale images has been swapped with a crop images action

Comment: If you look at the answer I linked, you can see the user's steps at the bottom include the exact same steps I used. I only swapped the scale images for crop images. I edited my original post to make it very clear what I did. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated the original post to show better screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are cropping twice. Maybe you must clear the clipboard between getting the variable because automator adds more info to the memory instead of replacing. Try placing an Applescript Action between the crops and paste this code to clear the memory:

```
tell application "System Events"
    try
        set the clipboard to {}
    on error err_message
        display dialog err_message
    end try
end tell
```